# View側の＠Modelの配列をループで回してjavascript配列に入れ替える方法

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller

asp.net MVCにて、.cshtml側に書いたjavascriptに、
下記コードのように@Model.dayDataList配列をjavascript内で作成した配列にループを回して1つずつ入れ替えたいのですが、@Model.dayDataList[i]のiが
「現在のコンテキストに'i'という名前は存在しません」となり使えません。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var lastMonth = new Date(year, month-1, 0);

  var dayCnt= lastMonth.getDate();
  var dataList = new Array();
  for(var i = 1; i< dayCnt;i++){
    dataList[i-1] = @Model.dayDataList[i-1]   //←ここでエラー
  }

  // ---略---

</script>
```

@Model.dayDataList[0]のように直接配列に値を入力すればデータはとれているのですが、javascript内で宣言した変数は@Modelでは使用できないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラー個所で使用されている i はjavascriptの変数であり、Razor上の変数としては使えません。
ちょっと実際に動作させてないのでミスがあるかもしれませんが、目的の動作のためには以下のようになるかと思います

```
@for(int i = 1; i < Model.dayDataList.Length; i++) {
    @:dataList[@(i−1)] = @(Model.dayDataList[i-1])
}
```

for文自体をRazor側で実行しています。forもiもC#側というような意味合いです。
生成されるhtmlにはfor文ではなく、ループした回数分の代入文ができあがります。